# AWS registering Active Directory: not showing the subnets in the vpc

Tags: active-directory, amazon-vpc, amazon-workspaces

I have a vpc created in oregon (us-west) region and have subnets created in each of three availability zones. and I checked in the workspaces documentation that these three AZs are allowed for workspaces.

[image]

And subnets are:

[image]

I have created an Active Directory in the vpc and in two private subnets:

[image]

Now when I am trying to register the Active Directory, I don't see the subnets for selection:

[image]

Not sure why it's not showing subnets to select